# M2_HOME setting its path upto bin

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to set the path of maven. First I set the M2_HOME variable to its folder then I set the path variable to bin, but when i do the mvn -version it shows maven home path upto bin.

I've tried setting the path manually and using set commands on cmd prompt.
I've properly set the jdk and java home.

First i set the home path for M2_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.6.1
```

Then i set the path in system variables

```
%M2_HOME%\bin
```

After this when I do mvn -version in cmd

```
C:\Users\AmarBal>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T00:30:29+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I don't know what is it that i'm doing wrong setting up the path, for this i think i am having problem building java files on eclipse java resource folder.

Comment: have you set %JAVA_HOME% and then add it to path  like %JAVA_HOME%\bin ??

Comment: i've set the java home properly.

Comment: you are getting correct output . this is the output latest mvn -version shows on command line

Answer (score 0):

@amar2108 You should be setting the path variable as

M2_HOME=C:\Softwares\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin

Now when you give mvn -version you should be getting this as Maven Home

Maven home: C:\Softwares\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1

Comment: What you are getting when you run mvn -version?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to set the Maven path:-
**M2_HOME = C:\Softwares\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1**

Add the following to path

**%M2_HOME%\bin**

**Note- Also when you are checking, check mvn -version from new command line**